# How to determine what value a variable is assigned to

Tags: python

im wondering if this is possible

basically i want to take variable that can have one of two values

for exmaple it  could be in the format gooogle.com or just google

what i am trying to do is take the variable web_site and see if it contains a .com address and then to remove this from the value and if it is just google then to do nothing

is this possible to do in python ?

is

```
  web_site, com = on.split(".")
```

the correct way to do this ? if so how can i first check the variable ? thanks, sorry just starting out with python !

EDIT

i guess the question is

how can i take the input of the variable web_site and determine if it has the .com after it

Thanks guys for the answers ! all great

Comment: You could just `split` it as you did and take the first index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to test if `on` ends with `'.com'` and define `web_site` with a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
web_site = on[:-4] if on.endswith('.com') else on
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if website.endswith('.com'): # If website ends with '.com'
    website = website[:-4] # Remove last 4 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a small function that does it

```
def firstPart(text, delim):
    if delim in text:
        return text.split(delim)[0]
    else:
        return text


>>> firstPart('google', '.')
'google'

>>> firstPart('google.com', '.')
'google'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using an "if" statement:

```
if ".com" in website:
    website, com = website.split(".")
```

An "if" statement is the best tool to use when you want to check something, and do something else only if that condition is true. An "if" statement will always take the form:

```
if RUN TEST HERE:
    CODE TO RUN ONLY IF TEST IS TRUE
```

You can also use the 'else' and 'elif' statements to branch further, and do different things if there's more than one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the portion you don't need with an empty string - if the offending text is not in the original string, it will do nothing.

```
>>> name = 'google'
>>> name = name.replace('.com', '')
>>> name
'google'
>>> name = 'google.com'
>>> name = name.replace('.com', '')
>>> name
'google'
>>>
```